# Google Webmaster Tools is reporting that some URLs listed my sitemap have a high response time

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, performance

In Google Webmaster Tools looking at a new clients site, I'm seeing sitemap errors that I haven't seen before with this message:

> Some URLs listed in this Sitemap have a high response time. This may
>   indicate a problem with your server or with the content of the page.

See the following screenshot:

[image]

I submitted the sitemap again but it keeps coming back. Any Ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

This message has nothing to do with the sitemap itself. It has to do with the response times of some of the pages listed within the sitemap. So resubmitting a sitemap does nothing for you.

I have gotten these messages before and was deeply concerned and tested my system from within the network and externally. I tested the pages in question and a whole host of other pages trying to figure out what was wrong.

I finally came to the conclusion that it had nothing to do with my site at all. Part of this time measure is a whole host of elements that all have to work perfectly and often does. However, slow DNS response times, poor routing, and so on can effect Google's ability to download your pages. But let us not discount that quite possibly your server was slow at the moment.

But then I remembered back to Google's own page speed tests that I conducted and how much higher they were when comparing them side-by-side with other tools. I came to the conclusion that no matter how massive the bandwidth Google may possess, there are too many elements between them and my site and perhaps my site was a bit slow, but Google over-reacted and that I would give it some time.

Sure enough. It was a temporary thing. Nothing to worry about unless systemic. I have not seen these messages again.